# Is where a way to create an SQL Server login with MSBUILD?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, msbuild, msbuild-task

I have to create a new SQL Server user for our application. To spare me the effort of doing it on each of our installations, I want our MSBUILD script to handle it. I have the login user and password as variables in the build script. The user shall only be data-reader.

Is there a way to do this easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of the [SQL Server Command Line Utilities](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53591) (there are different versions of this package, make sure you pick the one that matches your OS and is compatible with your version of SQL Server).

The [sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility) utility lets you enter Transact-SQL statements, system procedures, and script files at the command prompt.

You could now create a SQL script (e.g. *createuser.sql*):

```
USE [$(DatabaseName)]
GO

-- If the user exists, drop it first
IF EXISTS (select principal_id FROM sys.database_principals where [name] = '$(DatabaseUser)' AND type = 'U')
BEGIN
    DROP USER [$(DatabaseUser)]
END

-- Create it
CREATE USER [$(DatabaseUser)] FOR LOGIN [$(SqlLogin)]

-- And add it to the Role db_datareader
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [$(DatabaseUser)]
```

Using *sqlcmd* you can now call this script from the command line like so:

`sqlcmd -v DatabaseName="MyDatabase" DatabaseUser="Pete" SqlLogin="John" -i "createuser.sql" -S "mymachine\mySqlInstance"`

You could now create an *MSBuild* project file with an `Exec` task that will call that statement for you:

```
<Exec Command="sqlcmd -v ..." ... >
</Exec>
```

Please note that the user that is executing the sqlcmd should have permissions in Sql Server to perform the scripted actions. SqlCmd lets you specify a specific username and password.

Answer (score 0):

You can create sql user using

```
create user $(username)
```

Where $(username) will be your variable and passed with your parameter during msbuild execution